# Reset checkboxes in datalist on click of button that is outside of datalist using c#

Tags: c#, .net, checkbox, datalist

Reset checkboxes in datalist on click of button that is outside of datalist using c#

Comment: Not a very detailed question.  Are you talking about winforms? ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

In the eventhandler for the buttons OnClick event you'd loop trough each item in the datalist and find the checkbox and reset it.

Comment: foreach (DataListItem item in DataList1)
{ 
  
}

when i try like this it shows error. Plz provide me the source code.

thanks

Comment: you should use foreach(DataListItem item in DataList1.Items){}

Answer (score 0):

What CKret said and also, I often find the [Enumerable.OfType Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) method very useful to do things like that. Looping through components of some type in a collection of some sort. For example, somewhere I do something like this:

```
foreach(CheckBox c in somePanel.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
{
    c.Checked = false;
}
```

Comment: If I want to check whether atleast one checkbox is selected using javascript then how to do that?

Comment: javascript I don't know so well. In C# you can use the Any method like this: if(somePanel.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Any(ø => ø.Checked))

Answer (score 0):

Use this, i hope that help you:

```
foreach (DataListItem row in yourdatalist.Items)
{
   CheckBox check = row.FindControl("nameofthecheckbox") as CheckBox;
   check.Checked = false
}
```